# Chat onebox tag overflow

Tags: bug, design, chat

If I post a user profile with too many tags, it looks awful:

[image]

Comment: That's only because you don't have enough horizontal resolution.  The post looks fine to me in chat.

Comment: @MBraedley [Still needs fixing](http://rlv.zcache.com/css_is_awesome_coffee_mug-r90e8c5cbe97443ecab56bc41d8baa6f6_x7jg9_8byvr_512.jpg)

Comment: Shows up fine on 1600x900. Get a better monitor, guy.

Comment: Are we really going to be a community that says "your [computer spec] isn't good enough to view this site, upgrade your rig dawg?" Web layouts should never appear broken or janky, regardless of what resolution the user may be viewing the site on (not to mention that there are lots of legitimate reasons to be running at a lower resolution). It's a minor issue, so "it's too minor to fix" is a reasonable answer, but "it's your fault" shouldn't be (unless the user is using an unsupported browser).

Comment: @cloudymusic While what you said is true, I'm pretty sure Unionhawk was trolling...

Comment: Guilty as charged. But regardless, this is a rather minor issue occurring in limited cases. (but an issue all the same, I will agree)

Comment: Is this localised to Arqade's chat, or would this be a problem across all SE site chatrooms? If so, It may be worth raising on [metase]

Comment: @Robotnik It's fine to raise bugs on SE 2.0 metas even if the fix would potentially apply everywhere.